# ASP CORE Razor page, variable viewbag filter content with dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor-pages, viewbag

I have three dropdownlists that I fill with the contents of viewbag variables. I want the content of the second variable to be filtered when I select a value of the first using JQuery or javascript. The same with the third dropdownlist, which is filtered by what is selected in the second.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        function SelectedIndexChanged(accion, idnum) {
            var nuevaSelProyecto = "";
            var proyecto = "";
            var nombre = "";
            switch (idnum) {
                case "ddlSelContrato": {
                    //var getValue = document.getElementById('ddlSelContrato').selectedOptions[0].value;
                    var e = document.getElementById("ddlSelContrato");
                    var getValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
                    nombre = "Contrato, indice seleccionado: " + getValue;
                };
                    break;
                case "ddlSelProyecto":
                    nombre = "Proyecto";
                    break;
                case "ddlPtoStudio":
                    nombre = "Punto Estudio";
                default:
                    nombre = "Defecto";
                    break;
            }
            alert("Alerta, indice: " + accion + " - " + nombre);
        }

    </script>
    <div>
        <text style="margin-left: 8px;">
            &nbsp   Contrato &nbsp
        </text>
        @*--------------------Listado desplegable de Contrato--------------------------*@
        @Html.DropDownList("ddlSelContrato", new SelectList(ViewBag.SelContrato, "Id", "Nombre"), new { Class = "ddlStyle", onchange = "SelectedIndexChanged(this.value ,id)" })

    </div>

    <div>
        <text style="margin-left: 8px;">
            &nbsp   Proyecto &nbsp
        </text>
        @*--------------------Listado desplegable de Proyecto--------------------------*@
        @Html.DropDownList("ddlSelProyecto", new SelectList(ViewBag.SelProyecto, "Id", "Nombre"), new { Class = "ddlStyle", onchange = "SelectedIndexChanged(this.value ,id)"})
    </div>
    <div>
        <text style="margin-left: 8px;">
            &nbsp   Punto de Medicion &nbsp
        </text>
        @*--------------------Listado desplegable de Puntos de estudio--------------------------*@
        @Html.DropDownList("ddlPtoStudio", new SelectList(ViewBag.PtoStudio, "Id", "Nombre"), new { Class = "ddlStyle", onchange = "SelectedIndexChanged(this.value ,id)" })
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
       // GET: PuntoEstudios
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.SelContrato = _context.Contratos.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Nombre).ToList(); //Variable MVC donde paso a la vista el List de los Contratos
        ViewBag.SelProyecto = _context.Proyectos.ToList(); //Variable MVC donde paso a la vista el List de los Proyectos
        ViewBag.PtoStudio = _context.PuntoEstudios.ToList(); //Variable MVC donde paso a la vista el List de los pto de estudio

        return View();
    }
```

How can I do it without calling the server

Comment: What's the relationships between the three models, one-to-one or one-to-many?

Comment: relationships between your three models one-to-many,

Comment: So could you share the  three models' code which can clearly express the relationship between the three ?

Comment: The relationship is:
a contract can have many projects, 
a project can have many studies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the relationships between your three models like : Contrato-Proyecto(one-to-many),Proyecto-PtoStudio(one-to-many) . If you want to change the filter the value of dropdownlist without calling the server, you could refer to the below working demo:

*Models*

```
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

}
 public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<StudyPoint> StudyPoints { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Contact")]

    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
}
public class StudyPoint
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Product")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Controller , use [`Include()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) to load the related data

```
public IActionResult CascadeDropdownlist()
    {
        ViewBag.SelContrato = _context.Contact.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name).ToList(); 
        ViewBag.SelProyecto = _context.Product.Include(p=>p.Contact).ToList(); 
        ViewBag.PtoStudio = _context.StudyPoint.Include(s=>s.Product).ToList(); 

        return View();
    }
```

View and the javascript , refer to https://sung.codes/blog/2018/02/24/approximate-equivalent-linq-methods-javascript/ to use linq in javascript

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CascadeDropdownlist";
}

<h1>CascadeDropdownlist</h1>


<div>
    <text style="margin-left: 8px;">
        &nbsp   Contact &nbsp
    </text>
    @*--------------------Listado desplegable de Contrato--------------------------*@
    @Html.DropDownList("ddlSelContrato", new SelectList(ViewBag.SelContrato, "Id", "Name"),"Select value" ,new { Class = "ddlStyle", onchange = "SelectedIndexChanged(this.value ,id)" })

</div>

<div id="">
    <text style="margin-left: 8px;">
        &nbsp   Product &nbsp
    </text>
    @*--------------------Listado desplegable de Proyecto--------------------------*@
    @Html.DropDownList("ddlSelProyecto", new SelectList(ViewBag.SelProyecto, "Id", "Name"),"Select value" , new { Class = "ddlStyle", onchange = "SelectedIndexChanged(this.value ,id)" })
</div>
<div>
    <text style="margin-left: 8px;">
        &nbsp   Study point &nbsp
    </text>
    @*--------------------Listado desplegable de Puntos de estudio--------------------------*@
    @Html.DropDownList("ddlPtoStudio", new SelectList(ViewBag.PtoStudio, "Id", "Name"),"Select value" , new { Class = "ddlStyle", onchange = "SelectedIndexChanged(this.value ,id)" })
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function SelectedIndexChanged(action, idnum) {
            var nuevaSelProyecto = "";
            var proyecto = "";
            var name = "";
            switch (idnum) {
                case "ddlSelContrato": {
                    //var getValue = document.getElementById('ddlSelContrato').selectedOptions[0].value;
                    var e = document.getElementById("ddlSelContrato");
                    var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewBag.SelProyecto));
                    var getValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
                    var projectdata = array.filter(a => a.contactId == getValue);
                    $("#ddlSelProyecto").empty();
                    $('#ddlSelProyecto').append($("<option value=0>Select value</option>"));
                    projectdata.forEach(function (e) {
                        $('#ddlSelProyecto').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",e.id).text(e.name));
                    });

                };
                    break;
                case "ddlSelProyecto":
                     {
                    //var getValue = document.getElementById('ddlSelContrato').selectedOptions[0].value;
                    var e = document.getElementById("ddlSelProyecto");
                    var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewBag.PtoStudio));
                    var getValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
                    var projectdata = array.filter(a => a.productId == getValue);
                    $("#ddlPtoStudio").empty();
                    $('#ddlPtoStudio').append($("<option value=0>Select value</option>"));

                    projectdata.forEach(function (e) {
                        $('#ddlPtoStudio').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",e.id).text(e.name));
                    });

                };
                    break;
                case "ddlPtoStudio":
                    name = "Punto Estudio";
                default:
                    name = "Defecto";
                    break;
            }
        }
    </script>
}
```

*Result*
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will see to apply it.

Comment: It worked perfectly, thousand thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @PabloB, glad to help you resolve the issue. Could you mark it as answer so that other people who have the same or similar issue can find the answer quickly? Thanks a lot!