# How to have a ViewBag List Dynamic view with is created from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, viewbag, razor-2

I have HTML view which has ViewBag list as you can see in the code below.

````
                      ``` 
<select asp-for="categoryName" id="CatId" name="purchase[0].categoryName" class="form-control" style="border-radius: 12px; " asp-items="@ViewBag.Pitems">
                                    <option>Select Category</option>
                            </select>         
                             
                           <select asp-for="type" id="typeId" name="purchase[0].type" class="form-control" style="border-radius: 12px; " asp-items="@(new SelectList(string.Empty, "type", "type"))">
                                    <option>Select Type</option>
                             </select>
````

Now for other page want to use same thing but it is in javascript, When I write this code in Javascript ViewBag is not working

```
   var counter - 1;          '
<select  class="form-control"  asp-for="categoryName" name="purchase[' + counter + '].categoryName" style="border-radius: 12px; " id="cat1" onchange="change1(' + counter + ', this) asp-items="@ViewBag.Pitems";>'
```

This code is showing no value in dropdown, how to code javascript dropdown list which access ViewBag>

Comment: This doesn't work because the Razor C# is processed at the server before the page is delivered to the browser. The JavaScript is processed in the browser without access to the ViewBag. So you'd need to encode the ViewBag values into a JavaScript variable. See this question for techniques https://stackoverflow.com/q/10008023/2030565

Comment: @Jasen thank you for reply i did this  var myJsVariable = '@ViewBag.type'

        alert(myJsVariable); but i am still getting Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to serilize the ViewBag data in js function:

```
var obj = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewBag.model));
```

Take a look at this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61886045/11965297

**Example:**

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    List<ItemsType> type = new List<ItemsType>
    {
        new ItemsType{ TypeId = 1, Type = "A"},
        new ItemsType{ TypeId = 2, Type = "B"},
        new ItemsType{ TypeId = 3, Type = "C"},
    };
    ViewBag.type = type;
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Scripts:

```
<script>
    var types = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewBag.type));
    var select = document.createElement("select");
    $(select).attr("name", "purchase[0].type");
    $(select).attr("id", "typeId");
    $(select).addClass("form-control");
    $(select).css("border-radius","12px");
    $.each(types, function (index, type) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = type.typeId;
        option.text = type.type;
        select.append(option);
    })
    $("#container").append(select);
</script>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: great! I found it too but how can I add this variable "obj" in the Dynamic JavaScript code.

                    '<option value= (Here is where I would like to see the viewbag</option>' +
                    '</select>' +

I was trying to do a foreach loop in the option value but I could not figure out being it dynamic if you have an example it would be great1

Comment: Can you show the controller which you set the ViewBag, and the related model as well.

Comment: Sure is like this
'''
 IList<ItemsType> type = _context.ItemsTypes.ToList();
 ViewBag.type = new SelectList(type, "typeId", "type");

Comment: What you have sent me works for me but I would like to add that in a dropdown list I would like if you have any example of how to do it, I don't know if a loop has to be created or the variable can be added directly in the INPUT

Comment: @GermanBernal, sorry for being late, I have updated my answer.